# how can i make a sk-sprite-node to always be in the centre of the screen, when the other nodes come and go out of the view of the application?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I had tried infinite scrolling the background, but the node(the ball) required here sometimes goes above the view and reappears on the screen when the ball(the node) comes down with the gravity.

I need the ball to be in the centre of the screen.

I'm very new to programming, this is my first attempt in this.

Since i'm from a medical background(professionally) any advice would be of great use.

Thank in advance for any inputs.

Comment: Please give some context to the problem you are trying to solve. It is difficult for people to know what is wrong without being able to look at your work.

Answer (score 0):

```
ball.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2);//Centre for all devices
ball.zPosition = 10;//sprite z position
```

I dont understand well your question. If you can show your codes, I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

name the node you want to be in the centre of the screen as @"camera"

the use this code

```
    - (void)didFinishUpdate
{

    [self centerOnNode: [self childNodeWithName: @"//camera"]];
}

- (void) centerOnNode: (SKNode *) node
{
    CGPoint cameraPositionInScene = [node.scene convertPoint:node.position fromNode:node.parent];
    node.parent.position = CGPointMake(node.parent.position.x - cameraPositionInScene.x,                                       node.parent.position.y - cameraPositionInScene.y);
}
```

the required node is always in the centre of the view.

sourced from apple document 'Advanced Scene Processing'